PCB review of 14+14W TDA7269A amplifier
I have designed this PCB. I need someone to have a look and mention any flaw in design or improvements that can be made here.
TOP Layer:

BOTTOM Layer:

Schematics:


A flaw in this question is not providing any schematic and explanation what this circuit should do.

You need to add (schematic, PCB layer stack up, application of the board), then We can help with the review.

and I mean, there's a couple of things we can say about it without knowing its schematic (and sadly, due to missing schematic, these can only be negative things): 1. this is unnecessarily crowded. Especially for anything meant to amplify analog signals: give yourself space, will make it much easier to lay out well, and ease both measuring easier and reduce noise problems if you group functional units.


some component placements are "OK, nice, now rip it up and do it less stupidly" (this is normal during an early layout phase, don't worry!) For example, U2 seems to be connected to exactly 1 thing, and that 1 thing is literally on the opposite end of the board. Would have been easy to have an easier layout if you didn't choose exactly that position. Also, I suspect this is a linear 5V regulator, which you put there because it's a good place to attach a heat sink? You need to tell us about the mechanical boundary conditions here! Anyways, if you have a linear regulator that you need to cool,


you might need to not have that linear regulator, but a step down switching regulator, and potentially an LDO to smooth out switching noise, depending on what uses that 5V output.


looks to me as if you had "must keep the board dense, and use wide traces for power connections" in your head, but forgot to think about where the return currents for these high currents flow. Where's the ground connection that can carry as much current as your 12 V for U1? Do you think the "GND" loop on U1 will have exactly the same potential as the GND trace at U2, although the full current for U1 has to go all the way through the thin ground traces from U1 to your Jack to the two other connectors then to the external power connection? Think again!


This board should almost certainly be four-layer.

@MarcusMüller yes I placed U2 like that to attach it to the same heat sink as for U1

On the schematic, the audio input connections would be easier to understand if you actually drew the connections rather than depending on the net names to show the connections.  Likewise in the Power box, and the 7805 is upside-down there.  I dislike the practice of showing small sections of a circuit in little boxes, although your schematic is much less bad than some I've seen.

@Hearth Probably not – the chip it revolves around is a >20 year old car stereo amplifier IC. These things probably were designed for 2 layers; look at the datasheet single-supply schematic on page 7; this can definitely be routed on two layers (only place where two traces need to cross can be solved by routing "IN- (R)" under a 1 kΩ resistor)! Just needs more thought on floor planning, and probably more space.

@fghbnhj Can you post the archive of the KiCad files somewhere, or upload the project (individual files, not an archive) to GitHub? I can show you how to do it right, but I don't feel like drawing it up from scratch at the moment, I only got 20 minutes to work on this stuff today.

Hi, Maybe it is just me, I can see you have power and GND connected to U1, I just don't see it reflected in the schematic?

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica i have uploaded the files here https://www.mediafire.com/folder/5gm4fv5wfmt3l/KICAD+files
you can have a look

as said in the comments:

you have designed in a mute functionality (as in the reference schematic), but then have just connected it to 5V instead of an input. That makes no sense; if you don't want to use that, don't have it, and don't layout it. People have told you this in your previous question
you tried to lay out this on a board that seems to be very small. Make it twice as large, lay out the things in the logical groups as you do in the schematic, and things will be easier
U2:

on wrong end of board.
terribly old regulator with bad rejection of noise, voltage output will contain part of the audio signal at high volumes

this is mainly because you're "re-using" the decoupling capacitor of your amplifier chip as voltage source for your voltage regulator. Don't do that!


wrong choice of regulator architecture: you're dropping 7 V, and feeding an external connector that might draw quite a bit of current. That says "switching regulator", otherwise you will need cooling. Cooling is the reason why this thing is placed at the place where it is, but if you don't use a linear regulator, you don't get that constraint. People have told you this in your previous question. When getting design review, you need to incorporate the design review into your design, otherwise, what's the point?


You need to dimension your return current paths as beefy as the current paths. In other words: there should be as much GND as there is 12 V; the path that the current coming back from the speakers take to ground supply needs to be as thick as the sum of current paths into the speaker. This is low-frequency, so the actual distribution of fields is not as important, but it's still a good idea to ensure this by running a ground line below each signal line; in other words, by default, run only GND on the bottom, and the top is then used for signals. When you look at your schematic (which is mostly a copy of the reference circuit on p.7 of the datasheet, this thing can definitely be routed with everything on the top layer. You should do that, unless you want to figure out how to make sure you get a low-impedance ground everywhere you need it (again, in high-frequency circuitry you would need to have ground directly below signals, here it's just a simplifying measure). You will need more space to do that.
Generally, crossing from top layer to bottom layer is something you should only do "as an exception", not as the rule
your placement of C6 / C7 and C8 is very unnecessarily complicating. There's clearly very symmetrical input paths there, but yet you decided to put C8 in the middle of everything, instead of routing the input signals, including C6 & C7 as a "closed" unit, then putting your mute logic somewhere else, itself as unit.
in fact, most of your layout is unnecessarily complicating. You could have slightly rearranged your resistors and could have gotten away with no need to route signals on the bottom layer, you could have placed the decoupling capacitors more logically next to U1, you could have removed the mute logic or at least moved it out of the signal path
you're just randomly assigning trace widths. Why do you have wide traces between speaker connectors and the AC coupling capacitors, but then slim traces from there to the amplifier output? That makes no sense.
board is missing mounting holes, since this can't be a slide-in board, as there's connectors at two adjacent edges

Recommendations

remove mute logic. You're not using it.
remove linear 5V regulator. Without mute logic, you're not using it. If you need 5V for something external, use a switching regulator, which then doesn't have to be cooled
Use board in larger, standard size (e.g. 16×10 cm, 8×10cm) with mounting holes or enough space at the the edges for board holders.
place connectors that have to be in specific places, first.
place cooling-needing amplifier IC
place decoupling capacitors next to supply pins.
then, place components in functional groups (i.e., place the input stereo capacitors in symmetry, next to each other, between inputs and input pins of IC; place output components symmetrical, next to each other, between IC and outputs)
then, route all your signals on the top layer. As the schematic in the datasheet shows, that's possible, since there are no signals crossing (aside from one, which you can route under your R5)
route power. This will probably just be a trace around the functional units from the power connector to the IC's decoupling caps.


i was going to use a the linear voltage regulator to power up a small Bluetooth receiver. So . i should replace it with a switching regulator.

can you just once again explain about the trace widths as i couldn't completely understand what i am supposed to do

no, I'm sorry. I wrote it as clearly as I could.

Can you also explain how I should create a 5V switching power supply? I am fairly inexperienced in designing it myself


On a 2-layer board like that, you'll need a proper star ground. Right now there's a fair chance the circuit will oscillate now and then - there's feedback from output to input.

This will need to be mounted to a heatsink. No, the IC is not how you attach a PCB assembly to a heatsink. There needs to be mechanical connection between the board and the heatsink that is independent of the IC. Right now you have a board that "floats in space" with no way to actually mount it anywhere.

That schematic absolutely doesn't need to be made up out of blocks. It's such a simple circuit - use wires on the schematic, there is no excuse. Don't be "inspired" by the blocky mess of modern schematics. It's not hip, it's not cool. Schematics are a means of communicating engineering ideas. They are there to guide the eyes. Cutting things up into boxes does nothing but obscures how things are connected together.


Assembly procedure is also important:

Attach it to the heatsink using mounting brackets etc.
Put the IC's pins through the holes and mount the IC on the heatsink.
Only then solder the IC's pins. That way the pins will not be stressed.
Unmount the IC from the heatsink.
Assemble the rest of the board.

For assembling more than one of them, you'd 3D-print a jig to which you'd temporarily mount the PCB and amplifier IC to align it. The holes in the heatsink would need to be accurately machined not to overstress the chip. 3 decades ago you'd have a machinist make a jig from a tough plastic, or even aluminum.
